# Extracting from specific lines in a text file loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a file that looks like this

```
--------------Time step: 1 ---------------
Accumulated rewards: 1.5
Alpha: 660
Beta: 173
TCP_Friendliness: 1
Fast_Convergence: 1
State: 3
Retries: 0.0
---------------------------------------------------------------
---------------Time step: 2 ---------------
Accumulated rewards: 2.724744871391589
Alpha: 193
Beta: 0
TCP_Friendliness: 0
Fast_Convergence: 0
State: 3
Retries: 0.0
---------------------------------------------------------------
---------------Time step: 3 ---------------
Accumulated rewards: 3.869459113944921
```

I'd like to extract the time step values into an X array and the Accumulated rewards value into a Y array, I have no idea how to do that as I have 0 python experience, but this is my initial loop i've written that skips the first couple of lines that I have not included in the example(gibberish data)

```py
with open('Tuner_result_1.txt') as f:
    for _ in range(11):
        next(f)
    for line in f:
        x = [line.split()[0]]
        y = [line.split()[1]]
```

obviously the actions inside the 2nd for are incorrect, Im not sure how to read the lines i want in the manner I want properly.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Also reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  "I don't know how to write my program" is an issue for on-line or personal tutorials, not a Stack Overflow issue.

Comment: Okay thanks i will learn how to ask next time sorry for being so stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
myfile = open("Tuner_result_1.txt", "rt") # open lorem.txt for reading text
contents = myfile.read()         # read the entire file into a string
myfile.close()                   # close the file
#print(contents)  

import re
X = re.findall("Time step: ([0-9]+)", contents)

Y = re.findall("Accumulated rewards: ([0-9.]+)", contents)
print(X)
print(Y)
```

Output:

> ['1', '2', '3']
> ['1.5', '2.724744871391589', '3.869459113944921']

Comment: i was about to answer. but your one is quick upvoting your answer. Thanks

Comment: Id like to read from the text file not add it in my code, is that possible with this flow?

Comment: Sure @OmarHussein

Comment: You don't need to add `"t"` to access mode, cause it's set by default. Also read mode is set by default, so you can use `open("Tuner_result_1.txt")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply next regular expression: [`Time step: (\d+).+?Accumulated rewards: ([\d\.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nM19dn/2).

**Code:**

```
import re

with open("filename") as f:
    X, Y = zip(*re.findall("Time step: (\d+).+?Accumulated rewards: ([\d\.]+)", 
        f.read(), re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))
```

You can process each match separately:

```
X = []
Y = []
with open("filename") as f:
    for match in re.finditer("Time step: (\d+).+?Accumulated rewards: ([\d\.]+)", 
        f.read(), re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))
        x, y = match.groups()
        # do smth with x and y or add to list
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
```

You can also use string slicing:

```
X = []
Y = []
with open("filename") as f:
    s = f.read()
    x_idx = y_idx = 0
    while True:
        x_idx = s.find("Time step: ", y_idx)
        y_idx = s.find("Accumulated rewards: ", x_idx)
        if x_idx >= 0 and y_idx >= 0:
            x = s[x_idx + 11: s.find(" ", x_idx + 11)]
            y = s[y_idx + 21: s.find("\n", y_idx + 21)]
            # do smth with x and y or add to list
            X.append(x)
            Y.append(y)
        else:
            break
```